# Extract date & time from JSON data in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have the following data,

```
{"value": 0, "action": "UPDATED", "effectiveFrom": "2019-01-31T07:27:13.000Z"}
```

I am trying to extract the time value using the below SQL,

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN JSON_EXTRACT(changeData, '$.action') = 'UPDATED' THEN
          time(replace(JSON_EXTRACT(changeData, '$.effectiveFrom'), 'T', ' '))
         ELSE
          'N'
       END AS ACTION
  FROM change
```

I used the *replace* function having read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42305151/extracting-iso-dates-from-a-json-data-type) that for mysql the 'T' should be replaced.
My sql is returning null.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I just noticed that the time function returns 00:20:19.000000 for the sample data i gave but it is 07:27:13.000. Is there anything i missed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to replace double-quote and `Z` characters with `''` **or** `' '` while replacing `T` with `' '` character for the time literal as

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(changeData, '$.value') AS value,
       CASE
        WHEN JSON_EXTRACT(changeData, '$.action') = 'UPDATED' 
        THEN 
            TIME(
            REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
                                    JSON_EXTRACT(changeData, '$.effectiveFrom')
            ,'"',''),"Z",''),"T",' ')
            )
       ELSE 'N'
      END AS action
  FROM `change`
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dbb21f797419cea13682e313af785f6e)</kbd>

Comment: The time function returns 00:20:19.000000 for the sample data i gave but it should return 07:27:13.000.